# How to add fields to specific page templates

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I know how to add fields to `pages` by using `apostrophe-custom-pages`, but cannot figure out how to add field `x` only to page template `a`, and field `y` only to page template `b` in the `beforeConstruct` method. I have `console.log`ged both the `self` and `options` parameters passed to the function, but never see the template name within the log (and therefore allowing me to run logic within the `beforeConstruct` method. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is having two distinct `apostrophe-custom-pages` subclasses something you're going out of your way to avoid?

Comment: Nope, just not sure how to structure multiple `apostrophe-custom-pages` subclasses. At present, I am simply extending `apostrophe-custom-pages` by adding my own instance to `lib/modules`, which then obviously applies to my work in `lib/modules/apostrophe-pages`, where my additional templates are stored. Would I essentially create a new module in `lib/modules`, and initialize with `module.exports = { extend: 'apostrophe-custom-pages',...`? If so, how do I then include reference to this new template? Ran a quick test, and adding it to `apostrophe-pages/index` throws a not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have distinct schemas for different page types, you want an `apostrophe-custom-pages` subclass for each of those template types.

in `app.js` or divided among each module's `index.js`

```
const apos = require('apostrophe')({
  shortName: 'my-site',
  modules: {

    'default-pages': {
      extend: 'apostrophe-custom-pages',
      label: 'Default Page',
      name: 'default',
      addFields: [
        {
          name: 'customField',
          label: 'Special Label',
          type: 'string'
        }
      ]
    },
    'wacky-pages': {
      extend: 'apostrophe-custom-pages',
      label: 'Wacky Page',
      name: 'wacky',
      addFields: [
        {
          name: 'partyMode',
          label: 'Turn on party mode',
          type: 'boolean',
          choices: [
            { label: 'Yes', value: true },
            { label: 'No', value: false }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
```

Then in `apostrophe-pages` configuration you want to add those new subclasses as page choices to the `types` array

in `lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.js`

```
  // ... other pages configuration
  types: [
    {
      name: 'default',
      label: 'Default'
    },
    {
      name: 'wacky',
      label: 'Wacky'
    },
]
```

Then you want to create the corresponding templates as views in the `apostrophe-pages` module.

```
lib/modules/apostrophe-pages /
-- views /
-- -- pages /
-- -- -- wacky.html
-- -- -- default.html
```